# Cannot create GLFWwindow in C++ - glfwCreateWindow returns nullptr?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, glfw, glew

After running several tests on the code, I have determined that both GLFW and GLEW are initialised successfully yet when I try and create a `GLFWwindow*` object to be used with GLFW functions, the `glfwCreateWindow()` function returns a `nullptr`. Why is this and how do I fix it? Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#define GLEW_STATIC
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

const GLuint windowWidth = 500, windowHeight = 500;

int main()
{
    glfwInit();

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_RESIZABLE, GL_FALSE);

    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(windowWidth, windowHeight, "Learn OpenGL", nullptr, nullptr);
    if (window == nullptr) {
        std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window!" << std::endl;
        char myvar1; std::cin >> myvar1;
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    if (glewInit() != GL_TRUE) {
        std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLEW" << std::endl;
        char myvar2; std::cin >> myvar2;
        return -1;
    }

    glViewport(0, 0, windowWidth, windowHeight);
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
        glfwPollEvents();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }

    glfwTerminate();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Docs say "Windows: Window creation will fail if the Microsoft GDI software OpenGL implementation is the only one available."  What video card are you using, do you have the latest driver, and are you running remote desktop or in the console session?

Comment: Using onboard graphics of a 1.9GHz Celeron. I will try updating the drivers.

Comment: Use OpenGL Extensions Viewer to confirm that your GPU actually supports 3.3. I was running into the same issue, it turns out Parallels' GPU emulation only goes as far as 3.2, but that's what I get for trying to do graphics on a VM.

Answer (score 6):

This is probably because you are specifying version 3.3 for the context creation and your opengl version is lower than 3.3.

OpenGL: GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR and GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR are not hard constraints, but creation will fail if the OpenGL version of the created context is less than the one requested.

This might happen if you are using a laptop that has 2 GPU's. They do that for power-consumption reasons, most applications will be run with the standard GPU and for games for example it will use the high performance one.

For example my laptop has a built-in Intel(R) HD Graphics 3000(3.1 opengl version) GPU and a NVIDIA geforce gt 630M(4.4 opengl version) GPU.

You can see if your laptop has this functionality if you right click on an application shortcut and have the option "run with graphics processor": - "High performance (NVIDIA) processor" - "Integrated graphics (default)"

The problem is that the editor(eclipse/ms visual studio, etc..)(in which you run your code) will use the default one and usually has a much lower version of opengl than your other GPU.

You can fix this by always running your editor program with your high performance GPU.

If you're not using a laptop or only have one GPU then try updating your drivers.